# match only part of regex expression python

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with regex of python and I'm trying to get a match for what comes before a certain word. For example in the string "match.function" i'm only interested in the 'match'.

how should i write the regex?

thanks

Comment: Read up on capture groups

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you meant ".function" literally or as an example, but here it is either way:

```
# literally function
re.findall('w*(?=\.function)', s)

# function as example
re.finall('\w*(?=\.\w*)', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's called `Positive Lookahead`

Try this :

```
(\w+)\.(?=function)
```

In python:

```
import re
pattern=r'(\w+)\.(?=function)'
string1='match.function'
print(re.search(pattern,string1).group(1))
```

output:

```
match
```